# Python AudioSegment: exporting wav to mp3 increases file duration

Tags: python, mp3, wav, audiosegment

I have a wav file, with exactly 4 minutes and 24 seconds of duration. When i try to convert it to mp3 format whit this simple code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

AudioSegment.from_wav("wavfile.wav").export("mp3file.mp3", format="mp3")
```

the result is a mp3 file with 4 minutes and 30 seconds.
Where does those extra 6 seconds come from? and how to avoid it?